# Unzip only limited number of files in linux

Tags: unzip

I have a zipped file containing 10,000 compressed files. Is there a Linux command/bash script to unzip only 1,000 files ? Note that all compressed files have same extension.

Answer (score 5):

```
unzip -Z1 test.zip | head -1000 | sed 's| |\\ |g' | xargs unzip test.zip
```

- -Z1 provides a raw list of files
- sed expression encodes spaces (works everywhere, including MacOS)

Answer (score 1):

You can use wildcards to select a subset of files.  E.g.

- Extract all contained files beginning with b:

  unzip some.zip b*
- Extract all contained files whose name ends with y:

  unzip some.zip *y.extension

You can either select a wildcard pattern that is close enough, or examine the output of `unzip -l some.zip` closely to determine  a pattern or set of patterns that will get you exactly the right number.

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

```
unzip -l zipped_files.zip |head -1000 |cut -b 29-100 >list_of_1000_files_to_unzip.txt
```

I used cut to get only the filenames, first 3 columns are size etc.

Now loop over the filenames :

```
for files in `cat list_of_1000_files_to_unzip.txt `; do unzip zipped_files.zip $files;done
```

Comment: I would recommend for the second command:  cat list_of_1000_files_to_unzip.txt | xargs unzip zipped_files.zip  There are some issues with this answer (file names with spaces for example), but it should perform at least as well in all respects than the for loop.

Comment: Thanks ! That makes the command shorter!

If you look closely, there isn't any space in any filename.
1) list_of_1000_files_to_unzip.txt 2) zipped_files.zip  are the only filenames used here. 
What other issues do you see?

Comment: I was referring to spaces in the names of the zipped files.  xargs (and for) will split on spaces, making "C:\Documents and Settings\Ferret food recipies.doc" into: C:\Documents, and, Settings\Ferret, food, and recipies.doc (5 separate files)

Answer (score 0):

Some advices:

- Execute zip to only list a files, redirect output to some file
- Truncate this file to get only top 1000 rows
- Pass the file to zip to extract only specified files